# dataframe.loc[] causing chained indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas 0.18.0.
If I create a new dataframe by filtering an existing dataframe with .loc[], and then try to add a new column to the new dataframe, I get a chained indexing warning.

I am puzzled because I thought the whole point of using .loc was to avoid chained indexing.

Am I missing something, or  is this a bug?

Is the explanation that `newdf = df.loc[some_condition]` creates a newdf that is a view, not a copy, of the original?

The only way I found to get rid of the warning is to use copy.deepcopy :

```
newdf = copy.deepcopy( df.loc[ (df['a'] > 10)  | ( df['b'] > 10) , :] )
```

Is there another way?

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import copy

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=np.arange(0,100)
df['b'] = np.arange(0,100) * 2

newdf = df.loc[ (df['a'] > 10) | ( df['b'] > 10) , :]
newdf['x'] = 0
```

Generates this warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   newdf['x'] = 0

Comment: `DataFrame` already has `copy` method :`newdf = df.loc[ (df['a'] > 10) | ( df['b'] > 10) , :].copy()`  will remove the warning however, what is your intention here to modify the original or make a copy?

Comment: I want to modify newdf leaving df as it is. I noticed that if I reset the index of newdf I no longer get the warning, however I do not understand why.

Comment: `reset_index` is an explicit method to modify the df so a copy will be returned at that point, like I said you can call `copy()` on the df to make an explicit copy and avoid the warning

Comment: Thank you. So does .loc actually return a view and not a copy, or is the warning incorrect? If it returns a view, is it by design? I didn't find this in the documentation and am very confused.

Comment: PS As for DataFrame.copy, what does this mean exactly?  "actual python objects will not be copied recursively, only the reference to the object. This is in contrast to copy.deepcopy in the Standard Library, which recursively copies object data.". What is an example of 'actual python object' in a dataframe?

Comment: This seems to indicate that new objects with their own ids are not created rather just the data and references, not sure if in practical terms and in your case this really matters